# Make exception to gitignore file

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php

I have a .gitignore file that removes the 'vendor' folder when I commit my changes. But I want to make an exception to a folder inside the vendor folder.

I saw that it was possible with a ! before the line that I want to keep. But that doesn't for. This is my .gitignore file:

```
!/vendor
!vendor/jeroennoten
/vendor/*
```

But when I commit my changes it still removes the whole vendor folder.

What is wrong?

Comment: Hello @LordRaiders , in !vendor/jeroennoten ,jeroennoten is a file or a directory ??

Comment: @ChitrankDixit It is a directory with the front-end template I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `jeroennoten` is a directory, the following should get you what you want:

```
/vendor/*
!/vendor/jeroennoten
```

More information can be found on the official [documentation site](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

**NOTE:** The order in which the inclusions/exclusions is important.  i.e. first exclude everything in the folder, and then override specific folders within that excluded folder.

Taken from the above article:

> When deciding whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome)